# Automatic Garbage Collection

Tags: php, garbage-collection

I have an list of items that is stored in the `$_SERVER["my_key"]`. Are these items garbage collected automatically?

Comment: Why is this tagged C# and php both?

Comment: *(reference)* [Garbage Collection in PHP5.3](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/features.gc.php)

Answer (score 2):

If there's nothing referencing the list (e.g. when you `unset($_SERVER['my_key'])`), it will be GC'd sooner or later (at the latest, when your script terminates).

Answer (score 1):

$_SERVER is a superglobal array and all values in this array will be the one and only time garbage collected when the script finishes execution.